# Matrix mergesort code

Tags: c++

I have a problem with this code and I can't sort it out. The problem is that it just made one iteration of the recursive function, and them it prompt a segmentation fault.

The problem I'm working on is: I have K ordered vectors and I want to merge them in one mergedsort vector. My implementation push all the vectors in one matrix and recursively order them. The function is mergeKvectors.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class matrix
{
public:
    matrix(int filas, int columnas)
    {
        datos.resize(filas);
        for(int i = 0; i< filas; i++)
        {
            datos[i].resize(columnas);
        }
    }
    vector< vector<int> > datos;
    /*
 *
 * @brief Función para sobrecargar el operados == para dos vectores 
 * @param vectores : matriz en que cada fila corresponde a un vector 
 *                   ordenado
 * @return resultAux : vector ordenado a partir 
 */

matrix& operator=( const matrix  v2)
{
    matrix& m= *this;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->datos.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< this->datos.at(0).size();j++){
            this->datos[i][j] = v2.datos[i][j];
        }
    }   
    return *this;
}

};

//typedef vector< vector<int> > matrix; // tipo de dato matrix
/*
 * @brief Funcion para imprimir un vector< vector<int> >  
 * @param matrix v : matriz de tipo vector< vector<int> >  
 */
void print(matrix v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.datos.size(); i++) 
    {

        for (int j =0; j < v.datos.at(0).size(); j++)
        {
            cout << v.datos[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

/*
 * @brief Función combinar dos vector< vector<int> > en otro ya ordenado
 * por filas
 *
 * @param matrix v1
 * @param matrix v2
 * @return vector<int>
 */
matrix merge( matrix v1,  matrix v2){


    print(v1);
    print(v2);
    int f1 = 0,f2 = 0,c1 = 0,c2 = 0, fr=0, cr=0;

    matrix v_resultado(1,v1.datos.at(0).size()+v2.datos.at(0).size());

    //Meter números ordenados en el vector ordenado
    while(f1 < v1.datos.size() && f2 < v2.datos.size() && c1 < v1.datos.at(0).size() && c2 < v2.datos.at(0).size()){
        if(v1.datos.at(f1).at(c1) < v2.datos.at(f2).at(c2)){
            v_resultado.datos[fr][cr] = v1.datos.at(f1).at(c1);
            c1++;
            cr++;
        }
        else{
            v_resultado.datos[fr][cr] = v2.datos.at(f2).at(c2);
            c2++;
            cr++;
        }
        if (c1+1 % v1.datos.at(0).size()==0)
            {
                f1++;
                c1 = 0;
            }
        if (c2+1 % v1.datos.at(0).size()==0)
            {
                f2++;
                c2 = 0;
            }
        if (cr+1 % v1.datos.at(0).size()==0)
        {
            fr++;
            cr = 0;
        }

    }

    //Terminar de completar vector resultado
    for(f1; f1 < v1.datos.size(); f1++)
    {
        for (c1; c1 < v1.datos.at(0).size(); c1++)
        {
            v_resultado.datos[fr][cr] = v1.datos.at(f1).at(c1);
            cr++;
            if (cr+1 % v1.datos.at(0).size()) fr++;
        }

    }
    for(f2; f2 < v2.datos.size(); f2++)
    {
        for (c2; c2 < v2.datos.at(0).size(); c2++)
        {

            v_resultado.datos[fr][cr] = v1.datos.at(f2).at(c2);
            cr++;
            if (cr+1 % v1.datos.at(0).size()) fr++;

        }

    }
    print(v_resultado);
    return v_resultado;
}


/*
 *
 * @brief Funcion Recursiva que calculara  un vector ordenado 
 * @param vectores : matriz en que cada fila corresponde a un vector 
 *                   ordenado
 * @return resultAux : vector ordenado a partir 
 */

matrix mergeKvectors(matrix vectores)
{


    if (vectores.datos.size() <= 1)
    {
        cout << "Saliendo" << endl;
        print(vectores);
        return vectores;
    }


    int middle;
    if(vectores.datos.size()%2 == 0)
    {
        middle = vectores.datos.size()/2;
    }
    else
    {
        middle = (vectores.datos.size()/2) +1;
    }


    matrix up (middle ,vectores.datos.at(0).size());
    matrix down (vectores.datos.size() - middle,vectores.datos.at(0).size());   

    vector<int> Aux;



    for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< vectores.datos.at(0).size();j++){
            up.datos[i][j] = vectores.datos[i][j];      
        }
    }   


    for (int i = middle; i < vectores.datos.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< vectores.datos.at(0).size();j++){
            down.datos[i - middle][j]= vectores.datos[i][j];        
        }
    }   


    cout << "HE LLEGADO!!!" << endl;
    print(up);
    print(down);
    //Here is where the problem is
    up = mergeKvectors(up);
    down = mergeKvectors(down);

    /*int tama_columnas = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < vectores.datos.size();i++)
    {
        tama_columnas += vectores.datos.at(i).size();
    }*/

    matrix resultAux(1,up.datos.at(0).size()+down.datos.at(0).size());
    resultAux = merge(up, down);

    print(resultAux);
    return resultAux;   
}
/*
 *
 * @brief Funcion Principal: 
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    if (argc != 4){
        cerr << "Formato " << argv[0] << "<ruta_del_archivo_de_entrada>  <num_elem>  <num_vect>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int tam_vectores = atoi(argv[2]); //Tamaño vectores
    int num_vectores = atoi(argv[3]); //Número vectores

    int num = 0;
    string ruta=argv[1];
    ifstream archivo(ruta.c_str());
    // cargamos todos los vectores en una matriz de tipo vector<vector> 
    matrix vectorAux(num_vectores,tam_vectores);
    matrix vectorT (num_vectores, tam_vectores);
    vector< vector<int> >  vectorRes;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_vectores; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < tam_vectores; j++){
            archivo >> num;
            vectorT.datos[i][j] = num;          
        }
    }       


   cout << "------------------" << endl;

   vectorAux = mergeKvectors(vectorT);

    /*for (int i =0; i < vectorAux.size(); i++)
        cout << vectorAux[i]<<" ";

    cout << " " << endl;
    */
    print(vectorAux);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger to find out the cause of the segfault? You can give us more details then.

Comment: Why are you passing all your data around as values? You should pass them as references (or constant references when applicable.) And, if you want to return large data structures from functions painlessly, you need to provide mechanisms for "moving" as well as copying.